# What tool can I use to test .NET App Performance on a WinCE device?

Tags: performance, testing, compact-framework, windows-ce, performance-testing

I search some tools for testing .net cf 2.0 app which deployed on WinCe device.
I want something like jetbrains dot trace performance. I've try use visual studio profiler but they show only stats about descriptors and memory and process ugage. I want look what function, run, how many time they work, what work toolong. But all this info I didn't see in VS profiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using EQATEC profiler. This profiler works great on our compact framework apps.

http://eqatec.com/Profiler/

Comment: Thanks, this app help me find few slow places.